# How can I fix a broken PDF link when I click it?

Tags: pdf, hyperlink, urlencode

I am working on some feature improvements in SAP's e-transformation applications. E-Invoices from some of our customers have links. When I want to view it via SAP, it directs me to the link, but when I download PDF, the link is broken and does not work correctly. I also cannot view some invoices via SAP, I need to download and view PDF. We tried to find a solution by changing the PDF libraries, but it didn't work. First of all, my question is, why is the link in a PDF broken and what is the solution?
When I click this link:

[image]

The link is broken like this:

[image]

I think the link was sent correctly from the customer as I was displaying it correctly on SAP. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to find a solution?

Comment: SAP is a software company and published hundreds of software. Which software are you talking about?

Comment: As KJ said above, `%C2%AD` is the UTF-8 representation of the "special" character U+00AD SOFT HYPHEN, not the classic hyphen character U+002D HYPHEN MINUS (which would be encoded `%2D` in UTF-8). Fix it and try again to see what happens.